# Show incorrect data for persian UTF8 in JSON in Android Studio

Tags: java, json, android-studio, utf-8, persian

I am trying to get `Persian (UTF8)` data from SQL Server with JSON in Android Studio, But this give me incorrect type.

for example for `"ظزرظیریذرطب"` show `Ø¸Ø²Ø±Ø¸ÛŒØ±ÛŒØ°Ø±Ø·Ø¨`

and I use SQL Server 2014 and my database collation is Arabic_CI_AS

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem, in java IntelliJ (web server) use this code:

```
 jsonObject.put("Category", URLEncoder.encode(rs.getString("Category"),"UTF-8"));
```

and in android studio use this code:

```
u.setProject(URLDecoder.decode(jsonObject.get("Project").toString(),"UTF-8"));
```